# Finding the (12k+2)th derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives

> Find:
>   $$\frac{d^{12k+2}}{dt^{12k+2}}\left[e^{t\sqrt{3}/2}\cos(t/2)\right], k \in \mathbb{N}$$

The answer should not be dependent on the value of $k$, which I gathered to mean that $k$ is not in the final solution, but I am not entirely sure on that. I have managed to reduce it to:

$$Re(((((sqrt(3)+1)/2)^(6k+1))*e^(i*pi/6))*e^(t(sqrt(3)+i)/2))$$

However, I cannot seem to go further whilst also eliminating $k$ from the answer. How can I solve this question?

Comment: Hint: $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pm \frac{i}{2}\right)^{12k+2} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\pm \frac{i}{2}\right)^{2} = \frac12 \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: One approach might be to consider $$\frac{d^{n}}{dt^{n}}\left[e^{t\sqrt{3}/2}\cos(t/2)\right] = c(n) \left[e^{t\sqrt{3}/2}\cos(t/2)\right] + s(n) \left[e^{t\sqrt{3}/2}\sin(t/2)\right]$$ and look at how $c(n)$ and $s(n)$ evolve

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The derivative is a linear operator, just as well as the real part, so:

$$ \frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(\text{Re}\exp\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}\,z\right)\right)= \text{Re}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}\right)^n\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}\,z\right)\right). $$
Notice that $\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}$ is a complex number on the unit circle, namely $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{12}}$, a twelth root of unity.

Comment: Could you kindly explain in detail why $\frac d {dz}$ and $\Re$ commute?

Comment: If f(z)= p(z)+ i q(z) (where p and q are real valued functions of z) then R(f)= p(z) and d/dz(R(f)= dp/dz.  While df/dz= dp/dz+ i dq/dz and then R(df/dz)= dp/dz.